# How to make gpg-agent to use socket activation for all gpg command request

Tags: arch-linux, gnupg, systemd

I am using arch linux and using the gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27

I configured gpg with

System service at /home/vipin/.local/share/systemd/user/ and using **socket activation to start  gpg-agent.service**

```
gpg-agent-browser.socket  
gpg-agent.socket
gpg-agent-extra.socket    
gpg-agent-ssh.socket
gpg-agent.service
```

gpg-agent.service

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1)
Requires=gpg-agent.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised --enable-ssh-support
ExecReload=/usr/bin/gpgconf --reload gpg-agent
```

gpg-agent.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1)

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
FileDescriptorName=std
SocketMode=0600
DirectoryMode=0700

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

gpg-agent-ssh.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation)
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1) man:ssh-add(1) man:ssh-agent(1) man:ssh(1)

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
FileDescriptorName=ssh
Service=gpg-agent.service
SocketMode=0600
DirectoryMode=0700

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

gpg-agent-extra.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted)
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1)

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
FileDescriptorName=extra
Service=gpg-agent.service
SocketMode=0600
DirectoryMode=0700

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

gpg-agent-browser.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers)
Documentation=man:gpg-agent(1)

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
FileDescriptorName=browser
Service=gpg-agent.service
SocketMode=0600
DirectoryMode=0700

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

All thing are working fine with when i do git push. I am able to get  the gpg prompt and able to enter the password . the gpg-agent is starting due to socket activation

```
vipin      31480   17517  1 01:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised --enable-ssh-support
```

But when i tried to do an encrypted file using gpg using below command

```
gpg --decrypt -q --pinentry-mode=loopback ${XDG_DATA_HOME}/pass/other/systembackup.gpg
```

The data is getting decrypted, But when i tried to do
ps -eaf |grep gpg. I can see that two agents are running , one in daemon  and another supervised. How to make this command use socket activation?

```
vipin      32064   17517  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised --enable-ssh-support
vipin      32167       1  1 01:11 ?        00:00:00 gpg-agent --homedir /home/vipin/.local/share/gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon
```

Answer (score 3):

The second instance was launched because it serves a **different GNUPGHOME**, as can be seen from the `--homedir` option it was launched with.

(The default location is `~/.gnupg`, while yours was started for `~/.local/share/gnupg`.)

Different gpg directories will *always* have separate gpg-agent instances, as doing otherwise would defeat the point of having separate directories. (This is because gpg-agent is not only a pass­phrase caching service anymore – as of v2.1.x it's the process that handles *all* access to gpg's private keys in the `private-keys-v1.d` subdirectory.)

To avoid this, you would need to duplicate gpg-agent.service (and at least some of its .socket units) for every different GNUPGHOME that you might use, *or* stop using a custom GNUPGHOME.

(Note that even if GNUPGHOME is customized, recent GnuPG versions always keep the sockets in /run at a random-looking path, not directly in the "home" directory anymore; however, the path is deterministic as a hash of the home directory location and can be retrieved using `gpgconf --list-dirs`.)